Encryption and Searching JSON Data using Laravel
I'm working on a system that stores users' data in a JSON format. An example of table structure and JSON format is shown below.



Visitor Id
Visitor Name
JSON Data




101
John
{JSON_DATA_SHOWN_BELOW}


102
Doe
{JSON_DATA_SHOWN_BELOW}



{
 "fields": [
    {
        "name": "Email Address",
        "type": "email",
        "label": "Enter your email address.",
        "value": "name@email.com",
        "required": "false"
    },
    {
        "name": "Your Company",
        "type": "string",
        "label": "Enter Your Company",
        "value": "My Company Name",
        "required": "false"
    }
 ] 
}

Since it stores personal data, I need to encrypt the value properties of each object. This is pretty straightforward and I'm able to encrypt this. But the challenge is, the system has a requirement to search the records based on the field value. For example if user search "name@email.com", then the system should return back record corresponding whole record, say visitor id 101.
The challenge I'm facing is, I didn't find any efficient and secure solutions to achieve this feature. Solutions that I know but doesn't seems perfect are:

Retrieve all records at first, decrypt back each values and perform search operation. But this is not efficient as the system stores huge amount of data and this approach is not suitable.
I can add a hashed value of the data along with an encrypted value, so I can perform search operation based on hashed_value and decrypt back the actual data using encrypted value. This solves the problem, but still, it is not 100% secure as attackers could attack the hashed value with pre-computed tables or brute force attacks.

Is there any other secure and efficient way possible through Laravel & MySQL to perform encryption and searching, which I'm missing? All help would be much appreciated.

No method of searching JSON like you show will be efficient. You can't index it. If you want it to be efficient, then store data in conventional rows and columns (probably in a second table), and put an index on the value.

@BillKarwin The problem is the data to be stored is dynamic, which means for each visitors, data to be stored is different based on some other conditions. Some have to store email and company, while some stores phone numbers and vehicle number. So making a conventional table for it is may be impractical.

Indeed. So you want dynamic data structure, but you also want it to be optimized? I'm afraid that's what is impractical.

Straightforward encryption in an application is rarely great for databases. You need to check what enterprise grade solutions there are for encrypting data in a mysql database. Writing this yourself from scratch is a huge endevour! Start with mysql TDE: https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html

However, I must agree with Bill: searching within a json document is not particularly efficient. You may have to create functiional indexes to speed such searches up.

I wonder if you'd be better off using something like MongoDB instead of MySQL. I recently started working with it after years of working with MySQL, and was a little confused by the lack of a schema on Mongo's Collections, but it would allow for my dynamic structures (which seems to be what you're expecting with email vs phone number, etc.). Not sure about encryption though. But yeah, a JSON column in a MySQL table isn't going to be the easiest to search, especially if you add encryption/decryption on top of all of that.

@Shadow I don't think it's possible to make a functional index in this case. I'm assuming the JSON array does not have a predictable order. That is, the object with the "Email address" is not necessarily in the 0th position of the array.

What about adding a salt key to each value and creating a separate table of indexes for searchable fields along with their hased_value and salt key. By this way each value has a unique hash value, at the same time for searching, system can look for index table first. What you think @BillKarwin
